# Connect to SQL Server using Powershell with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, powershell, authentication

My Powershell script uses Connection Strings to connect to the sql server instance and with executeReader gets the data.

Now to connect using current windows authentications of the system user,

```
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=$SrvName; Integrated Security=true;"
```

But In case I want to use alternate windows authentication credentials and note the I do not want to use SQL Server Authentication but windows authentication with alternate credentials and not the current credentials i.e

This uses SQL Server Authentication, right?

```
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=$SrvName; UserName=User1; Password=pwd;"
```

I don't want it.

I want a ConnectionString with Username, password input but uses Windows Authentication with those given inputs.

Comment: You can't specify different Windows credentials in the connection string.  See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66014/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-in-a-different-domain

Answer (score 0):

From the Powershell icon or shortcut hold the shift button while you right click.  This will open up a menu with the option to run the application as a different windows user.  Note, this does not work from the start menu only from a shortcut on the taskbar or other folder or from the .exe itself.

[image]

Comment: Holding shift works from anywhere, it is not required to be done via a shortcut. I do this from the start menu all the time. Unless you are on something older than Windows 7.

Comment: I tried it on Windows 10, didn't want to seem to work.